# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, attributeerror

```
article_content = []
for url in li:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    article_content.append(soup.find("div", {"class": "article-content"}).text)
```

gives the error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[19], line 5
      3 response = requests.get(url)
      4 soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
----> 5 article_content.append(soup.find("div", {"class": "article-content"}).text)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I am working with a list of websites and it throws error like above. My target is to store website scraping and store the article content in a separate text file. Thank you in advance for help!!

Comment: It means `bs4` didnt find any `div` element with class `article-content`. Try splitting these steps. Before you  try to extract text from article content, you need to check if its none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause of limited details in question here a general answer - There seems to be no element with class `article-content`, for several reasons:

- no site with article content
- content is rendered dynamically via javascript (use api/xhr or selenium)
- captcha / cloudflare blocked
- ...

Always and first at all check your `response` / `soup` if it contains expected HTML

You could use an `if-statement` to handle the error:

```
for url in li:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    article_content.append(
        soup.find("div", {"class": "article-content"}).text if soup.find("div", {"class": "article-content"}) else 'no element available'
    )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight I can understand the problem. Now i am trying to solve the problem.